# How do you return a value from a method and call it in another method?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to get a method to return either one value or another, and use that answer to fulfill an if clause in another method. In my isWinner method, I have:

```
public int isWin(int player)
{
    if(((board[0][0]+board[0][1]+board[0][2]==3)||
        (board[1][0]+board[1][1]+board[1][2]==3)||
        (board[2][0]+board[2][1]+board[2][2]==3)||
        (board[0][0]+board[1][0]+board[2][0]==3)||
        (board[0][1]+board[1][1]+board[2][1]==3)||
        (board[0][2]+board[1][2]+board[2][2]==3)||
        (board[0][0]+board[1][1]+board[2][2]==3)||
        (board[2][0]+board[1][1]+board[0][2]==3)))

    {
        return 1;
    }

    else if(((board[0][0]+board[0][1]+board[0][2]==6)||
             (board[1][0]+board[1][1]+board[1][2]==6)||
             (board[2][0]+board[2][1]+board[2][2]==6)||
             (board[0][0]+board[1][0]+board[2][0]==6)||
             (board[0][1]+board[1][1]+board[2][1]==6)||
             (board[0][2]+board[1][2]+board[2][2]==6)||
             (board[0][0]+board[1][1]+board[2][2]==6)||
             (board[2][0]+board[1][1]+board[0][2]==6)))

    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Where I am trying to either return 1 or 2. In another method, displayWinner(), my code checks to see of isWinner returns 1 or two and prints out different text according to what is returned by isWinner():

```
public void displayWinner()
{
    if(isWin()==1)
    {
        System.out.println("\n Player 1 wins...!!");
        isFull=true;
    }
    else if(isWin()==2)
    {
        System.out.println("\n Player 2 wins...!!");
        isFull=true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(isFull)
        {
            System.out.println("It is a tie.");
        }

    }
}
```

How do I return 1 or 2? Every time I call them, I get:

```
$ javac TicTacToe.java
TicTacToe.java:113: error: method isWin in class TicTacToe cannot be 
applied to given types;
            if(isWin()==1)
               ^
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
TicTacToe.java:118: error: method isWin in class TicTacToe cannot be 
applied to given types;
            else if(isWin()==2)
                    ^
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 2 errors
```

Comment: Your `isWin` method has a parameter (an `int` named `player`) but you're attempting to call it with no arguments. Is the parameter even necessary? You don't appear to use it within the method...

Comment: Also, you do not have a default return value in `isWin`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code isWin(int player) method requires one argument to be passed however while calling you are passing no argument to this method. That's why you are getting error.

So instead of calling as isWin(), call like this: isWin(1) or isWin(2)